# Cache invalidation and cache server restart

Tags: caching, redis, failover

My application is resilient to cache server restarts (well, want to be, but never mind that). That means that if the cache (Redis, in master/slave cluster configuration) becomes unavailable (e.g. the entire cluster becomes unavailable) the application can gracefully degrade by turning off cache-heavy features and still work - slowly.

Since I'm working with Redis in master/slave mode, I must save the state to the file system for the master-slave sync to be even remotely efficient. This means that when a server is restarted, it loads the data it saw from the previous incarnation.

The above works great until I need to send a cache invalidation message when the entire cluster is down. The flow is like this:

1. Cache is OK
2. App server puts data X=Y into cache. X=Y is saved to the cache file system.
3. Cache fails, goes to restart.
4. App server gets a command to manipulate X to be Y' - wants to send cache invalidation for X. Fails - cache is not responding (still down). Since cache is optional, app server logs and continues.
5. Cache goes back up - load data from the file system, including X=Y
6. App server gets a request to serve X - goes to the cache and sees the previous data X=Y. Y is being served even though the database has Y'. Problem. Angry customers.

How can this be solved - specifically in Redis with master/slave scenario (slave is currently used only for faster failover).

Comment: can you elaborate this: "I must save the state to the file system for the master-slave sync to be even remotely efficient"

Comment: I may have been mistaken. I'm assuming that for master-slave sync an RDB file must be saved. Is this RDB file not used for restarts? Also, if I disable it, what would it mean when a new slave connects? Will the server slow down to create a snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about cache here I would recommend this two approaches:

- skip RDB, you dont need it for replication to work properly
- when redis and your app cant communicate (eg. network split) anymore flush your cache on redis